# Why am I getting undefined index from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm new to javascript and am basically trying to create a dropdown menu which displays file names. A user would then select one and that file retrieved from the database and opened onto my canvas. I can't figure out how to pass the selectedText variable to my php select statement.

I'm sure this line is the problem

- $st= $_POST['selectedText'];

***the db file***

```
  $st= $_POST['selectedText'];

try{

$stmt = $user->runQuery("SELECT canvas_json FROM Tactical_canvas WHERE canvas_name = ':st'");

$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

} catch(PDOException $ex){
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
echo $result[0]['canvas_json'];
```

**the javascript should send the selectedText value which has been selected from dropdown. If I use an alert i can see the right value being selected, but php not receiving it...**

```
$("#Open").click(function(){
            openCanvas();
    });

    $("#select_option").on('change', function(){
        chooseCanvas();
    });


    function chooseCanvas(){

        var canvasSelect = document.getElementById("select_option");
        var selectedText = canvasSelect.options[canvasSelect.selectedIndex].value;


    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'canvasLoadByName.php',
    data: {selectedText: selectedText},
    success: alert(selectedText + " has been selected!")

        });

    }
```

**openCanvas should then display the choice made and is working perfectly if I manually input a value to select**

```
function openCanvas(){
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "canvasLoadByName.php",
    data: "json",
    success: function (result){
                canvas.loadFromJSON(result);
                canvas.renderAll();
                fabric.log(result);
            }
    });     

}
```

**the html**

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default button-group action cyan darken-4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#uploadFile2">Upload2</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="uploadFile2" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Upload File</h4>
        </div>

       <?require'canvasLoad.php'
       ?> 
<option value="showAll" selected="selected">Choose a file to open</option>

<div id="select_box">
<option>Select canvas</option>
<select id="select_option">
       <?php
        foreach ($result as $row) {
        echo "<option>".$row['canvas_name']."</option>";
        }

?>
        </select>

</div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
         <button class="btn btn-default button-group action cyan darken-4" id="Open" data-dismiss="modal">Open</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="Cancel">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You did not bind a parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

You might need to encode the json data before echoing the data out.

like  `echo json_encode($result[0]['canvas_json']);`

You need a semi-colon to end the require statement in your html file.

```
<?require'canvasLoad.php'
?>
```

Should be:

```
<?require'canvasLoad.php';
?>
```

Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php

Edit: You should also make sure to use `<?php` instead of `<?` when opening PHP tags. Unless enabled in your php.ini file it won't be read.

Comment: Thanks tried that but still not working. I'm specifically getting the error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1Undefined index: selectedText' so it is not being received from ajax but I've tried so many ways..

Comment: Did you try adding php to your opening tags? Like '<?php'.

Can you see what request is being sent in your developer tools?

Comment: Thanks Adam, I have updated my code with your advice. Although this is probably good to have done anyway it's not causing my error. The reason I didn't use json_encode is because it displays the JSON with backslashes and is apparently already encoded with Fabric JS canvas library that I am using.

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong you are calling same file "canvasLoadByName.php" from 2 ajax functions. One ajax function is using post method and other with get method and as per your code spinet you are trying to get every time post variable "$st= $_POST['selectedText'];". You should use some case to handle this or just use "isset()" method to fix issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think you're probably right but I don't know how to go about handling this. I am a complete noob! I want to post the selectedText variable to be used in the SELECT statement then display the results of this with my get function. Any advice is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Edit #2 (warning, long post ahead):
I took the code you posted in your initial question and slightly modified it. 
I suppose you would like to achive something like this:

Step 1:

[image: canvas selection]

Step 2:

[image: alert window with selected canvas name]

Additional debug output in console:

[image: console output]

Database table schema:

[image: database table schema]

dropdown.php:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default button-group action cyan darken-4" data-toggle="modal" 
        data-target="#uploadFile2">Upload2
</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="uploadFile2" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Upload File</h4>
            </div>

            <?php require 'canvasLoad.php'; ?>
            <option value="showAll" selected="selected">Choose a file to open</option>

            <div id="select_box">
                <option>Select canvas</option>
                <select id="select_option">
                    <?php
                    foreach ($result as $row) {
                        echo "<option>" . $row['canvas_name'] . "</option>";
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <br><br>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-default button-group action cyan darken-4" id="Open" data-dismiss="modal">Open
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="Cancel">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#Open").click(function () {
        openCanvas();
    });

    $("#select_option").on('change', function () {
        chooseCanvas();
    });
    function chooseCanvas() {
        var e = document.getElementById("select_option");
        var selectedText = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'canvasLoadByName.php',
            data: {selectedText: selectedText}
        }).done(function (result) {
            alert(selectedText + " has been selected!");
            result = JSON.parse(result);
            console.log(result);
            *// do whatever you want with the json data here*
        });
    }
    //openCanvas should then display the choice made and is working perfectly if I manually input a value to select
    function openCanvas() {
        var e = document.getElementById("select_option");
        var selectedText = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "canvasLoadByName.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {selectedText: selectedText}
        }).done(function (result) {
            //canvas.loadFromJSON(result);
            //canvas.renderAll();
            //fabric.log(result);
            console.log(result); // debug output
            *// do whatever you want with the json data here*
        });
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

canvasLoad.php

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test;host=127.0.0.1', 'username', 'password');
try {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tactical_canvas");
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch(PDOException $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

canvasLoadByName.php

```
$st = $_REQUEST['selectedText']; // I know, I know...
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test;host=127.0.0.1', 'username', 'password');
try {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT canvas_json FROM tactical_canvas WHERE canvas_name = :st");
    $stmt->execute(array(':st' => $st));
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch(PDOException $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

If it is still not working for you or if it is not what you were looking for, I'm sorry. If questions arise, feel free to ask.

---

Edit #1: @Adam Patterson is right, you need to json_encode() the output. Also, a distinction of cases whether it is GET or POST would be useful.

In the line

```
$stmt = $user->runQuery("SELECT canvas_json FROM Tactical_canvas WHERE canvas_name = ':st'")
```

you use a named parameter (:st), but

```
$stmt->execute();
```

should be

```
$stmt->execute(array(':st' => $st));
```

so your parameter actually gets populated with the value from your $_POST variable. This should be the main reason your application doesn't work as you want it to.

In your Ajax GET request,

```
data: "json"
```

should be

```
dataType: "json"
```

since your are not sending "json" as data (I suppose).

```
<?require'canvasLoad.php'
   ?>
```

is missing a semi-colon (and <?php is preferable for better portability, but lastly a personal preference)

Comment: Thanks for this! I still can't get it working based on your suggestions and like a few of you have suggested it is probably the get and post calling the same php file but I don't really have any idea on how to handle this unfortunately. All suggestions welcomed thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

**I upvoted all because you all gave me great advice so thanks very much for all of your help.**

**I changed my javascript so there was only method being used for both the select tool and the open button and it is now working seemingly flawlessly.**

**My noob brain is still not sure why this wasn't working in the format I had prior but obviously something to do with two functions calling the same php file.**

**Incase it helps or is of interest to anyone I've put below what I had to change which was basically just turn two javascript functions (openCanvas and chooseCanvas) into one.**

```
function chooseCanvas(){

    var canvasSelect = document.getElementById("canvas_name");
    var canvas_name = canvasSelect.options[canvasSelect.selectedIndex].text;


        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "canvasLoadByName.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {canvas_name: canvas_name},
        success: function (result){

                alert(canvas_name + " has been selected!"),
                $("#Open").click(function() {
                    canvas.loadFromJSON(result);
                    canvas.renderAll();
                    console.log(result);

            });
        }
     });    

}
```

**the php unchanged except I changed $st to $canvas_name.**

```
$canvas_name= $_POST['canvas_name'];


try {

$stmt = $user->runQuery("SELECT canvas_json FROM Tactical_canvas WHERE canvas_name = '$canvas_name'");

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


} catch(PDOException $ex){
    echo $ex->getMessage();

}

echo ($result[0]['canvas_json']);
```

**I tried changing**

```
$stmt->execute();
```

**to as suggested (except with canvas_name instead of st**

```
$stmt->execute(array(':st' => $st));
```

**I don't get any differences in result..**

**Cheers**